# How to measure outgoing connections limit?

Tags: networking

Is there any way to measure the maximum number of outgoing connections I can establish into the Internet? I use Linux and have no outside server to try connecting to. My goal is to optimize the background torrents so that they work on their maximum while not interfering with browser.

Comment: Your best bet is just tuning it all by hand. You stated in one comment you know 100 doesn't work but 60 does. Up it by half and try again. If this fails half that and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear.  Are you talking about the scientific number?  Or the number of useful connections for performance/bandwidth reasons?  Here is the scientific/software limit answer:

```
root@ac1:/data# netstat -an --inet | head
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:61616           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60818           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

This will print all the connections currently open.  Here is some info on tuning ephemeral port pools in linux:

http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html#Linux

Comment: I am asking not about the currently open connections, but number of connections I CAN open. For example, at home, if I allow torrent to make up to 100 connections, all other apps lose the ability to connect. However, if I allow only 60, other apps work normally. It is not a bandwidth problem, but a number of connections only. I want a faster way to get the max number than starting a torrent of ubuntu iso and counting its connections.